# a moving JLabel in java

Tags: java, jlabel

This is the programe that doesn't work:

```
    JLabel pic[][] = new JLabel[7][9];

    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < 70; i ++){
            pic[x_position][y_position].setLocation((10 + 70 * x_position) + i, (10 + 70 * y_position));
            pic[x_position2][y_position2].setLocation((10 + 70 * x_position2) - i, (10 + 70 * y_position2));

            Thread.sleep(5);  
        }
    }
    catch(Exception f){
    }
```

It shows up at the last position after the delay, but it wasn't moving, does anyone know why? And how do I improve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, go read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understand why you are having issues

Second, go read [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for solution to your problem

The solution might look something like this...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (count >= 70) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            return;
        }
        pic[x_position][y_position].setLocation((10 + 70 * x_position) + i, (10 + 70 * y_position));
        pic[x_position2][y_position2].setLocation((10 + 70 * x_position2) - i, (10 + 70 * y_position2));
    }
});
timer.start();
```